# How to install json gem - Failed to build gem native extension(mac 10.10)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, xcode, macos

*OS: Mac OS X 10.10.3 XCode: Latest with command line tools installed (version 6.3) Rails: version 4.2.1 Ruby: version 2.2.1*

I was trying to generate the routes for a project I am working on (been doing that on regular basis), when I got an error message, with a recommendation that I do bundle install and bundle exec. I did, and this time around, the process broke off while compiling the JSON Gem (version 1.7.7).

Doing some research on StackOverflow, the recommendation was to update the Xcode's command line tools, and I did, but that did not solve the problem.

I tried installing the JSON version 1.7.7 separately, and it failed, telling me to look for the error log in:

```
/Users/zwb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150411-36070-1t083xl.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:47: error: too few arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
    VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                                              ^
/Users/zwb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:793:9: note: macro 'rb_str_new' defined here
#define rb_str_new(str, len) __extension__ (    \
        ^
In file included from generator.c:1:
./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:11: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'VALUE' (aka 'unsigned long') with an expression of type 'VALUE (const char *, long)' [-Wint-conversion]
    VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
          ^        ~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Sad, however, JSON-1.7.7 (and upto 1.8.1) is [incompatible](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/229) with Ruby-2.2.x. As you are using Ruby-2.2.1, it will not work for you.

There are **2 options** for you:

1. Update your `json` gem to `1.8.2` version. -- **Preferable**
2. Edit `ruby-2.2.1/ext/json/fbuffer/fbuffer.h` file and replace problematic code with `VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PTR(fb), FBUFFER_LEN(fb));`. Look [here](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/229#issuecomment-68802010) for details

Comment: Thank you for your help! As you told, I modified gemfile, then install 1.8.2. Now it works OK!

Comment: Note if you use chef, older versions (e.g. 11.12.x) have a [dependency on the `json` gem with a version contraint locking it below 1.8.1](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/11.12.8/chef.gemspec#L30). Newer versions of `chef` (e.g. [11.18.x](https://rubygems.org/gems/chef/versions)) [no longer have `json` gem as a dependency](https://github.com/chef/chef/commit/32181f8d0ae1b0fbb18311742ace585099f68c4a).

Comment: I also had to change the json version in my gemfile for this to work.

Comment: This is great, except i'm getting this issue with 1.8.2

Answer (score 56):

If you are using Ruby 2.2.0 or greater, the json gem will not compile properly. You can fix this by issuing `bundle update json`

Comment: bundle update json worked for me on Windows 7 to bump the json version from 1.8.1 to 1.8.3.

Comment: This worked for me on a cloud9 rails VM. Thanks :) (I was running ruby 2.3.x)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer at least for OSX. Thanks a lot

Comment: For me, this doesn't work since the original installation does not work and I get This Bundle hasn't been installed yet. Run `bundle install` to update and install the bundled gems.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, since I downloaded basic Ruby by accident.

### 1.

Install the Ruby "Development Kit" here: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
Click the self-extracting file, and extract it here:

#### C:\RubyDevKit

(or somewhere else, but I had problems in other directories)

### 2.

Open the cmd (terminal): 

`cd C:\RubyDevKit
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb install`

Source: http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/1-ruby-and-devkit/

Comment: this one worked for me, it might not be obvious but installing the non dev package was the problem, and this was on Windows. In case a poor soul is trying to find this as I was, this is a bit of the error I was having `process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -I` and `make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.`

Answer (score 0):

gem install json -v '1.8.2' worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem as well, and none of the suggested fixes here solved it.

I was only able to resolve it by manually re-downloading and re-installing the appropriate version of the Xcode command line tools:

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=command%20line%20tools