# "bundle install" - error installing json 1.8.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-2.3

I have just cloned code to my newly minted Ubuntu Server environment running in VirtualBox.

After typing `rake db:reset` to setup the database, I received an error saying to run `Bundle Install` because my bundle was locked to **JSON 1.8.1** but that wasn't listed in any of the sources listed in my Gemfile.

I ran `Bundle install` and got the error pictured (haven't figured out how to copy/paste text out of my vm yet).

I'm running **Ruby 2.3.1** and everything has been updated/upgraded.  I've tried manipulating the Gemfile, Gemfile.lock, and re/installing json with no luck.  Previous solutions seems to come around the 2011-2013's but nothing recent.

It's been a day+ of banging my head against the keyboard - I'm guessing it has something to do with using old code on a newer implementation of the environment?

Help would be much appreciated.

[image: img]

[image: img]

Comment: this is a type of error that can be a little hard to interpret until you've done it a few times. It tells you to make sure the `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` command succeeds - If you run that command you will see a more informative error. You probably will need some system dependency a la `apt-get` or `brew`. By the way, if you're facing weird gem errors it's generally worth a try to prepend `bundle exec` to the command - this will make sure the version in the Gemfile is used and not the system version.

Comment: you are correct max, i tried installing json 1.8.1 and it ran into errors expecting 2 arguments but only getting one for something called fbuffer and then it cascaded to fall apart at that point.  perhaps I should delete this question and put that error up?

Comment: no need to delete the question. Just add the error.

Comment: whenever you see something about "native extension" popping up you have to install some library on your system. In this case I'm not sure which but the two files in the last lines of json install error text should tell you.

Comment: @maxpleaner friend of mine found this obscure post in SO that helped me get this working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578142/how-to-install-json-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extensionmac-10-10 - I changed my Gemfile.lock JSON line from 1.8.1 to 1.8.2 and bundle install + rake db:reset worked!  Now to see if my application functionality is still sound.  Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: cool ... maybe post as an answer so others can find it.

Answer (score 0):

friend of mine found this obscure post in SO that helped me get this working: stackoverflow.com/questions/29578142/… - I changed my Gemfile.lock JSON line from 1.8.1 to 1.8.2 and bundle install + rake db:reset worked! Now to see if my application functionality is still sound. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: You should encouraged your friend to register on SO so that you can give them credit for it.